# Grouping multiple records into one row while aggregating values in one field

Tags: mysql

Currently I have a set of records like this

[image]

I need my result into one row where I basically remove Field4 and aggregate the values in Field5

Basically like this

[image]

Is there a way I can group by the first 3 fields and aggregate the 5th field ?

Comment: You are already using all the right terms in your description ("group by the first 3 fields", "aggregate the 5th field") that seem to directly hint at what you should do (group and aggregate) and how (what to group by and what to aggregate). Just out of curiosity, how did that not ring any bells for you?

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking seems to be a simple SUM + group by:

```
SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3, SUM(Field5) AS Field5
FROM TheTable
GROUP BY Field1, Field2, Field3
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for ! Thank you